# byte [] to String conversion and again back to byte [] using UTF-8 encoding is not giving same byte array

Tags: java

To understand more on bytes, char and String in Java, I took a sample byte [] and converted to String and then from string converted to byte [] back. However I realized that original byte [] and new byte [] are not same. Why? Any help.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

        byte [] originalStringBytes = {39, -94, 17, -18, 43, 32, 50, -70, 31, -125, -46, 10, -23, 32, -112, 63};
        //Convert into string 
        String convertedString = new String (originalStringBytes, "UTF-8");
        //Now again get the bytes back from string 
        byte [] afterStringConversionBytes = convertedString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        //compare two byte array, both are not same
        if(originalStringBytes.length == afterStringConversionBytes.length) {
            System.out.println("SAME");
        } else {
            System.out.println("DIFFERENT");
        }

     }
}
```

It printed "DIFFERENT"  for me.

Comment: If you only use Hex UTF-8 bytes, it should convert just fine. Try `byte [] originalStringBytes = {39, 17, 43, 32, 50, 31, 10, 32, 63};`

Comment: yaa, that worked, but it doesn't explain why it didn't work my sample, I am working on crypto logic and for that I was just experimenting to understand this.

Comment: Just as Joni answered. When you say convert from/to `UTF-8` you are laying out the constraints on the characters you can convert to/from.  Here are the [valid](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence of bytes has to follow strict rules to be valid utf-8 encoded text. What you have in the array does not follow these rules, and can't be converted into a string without losing information.

The rules are explained for example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8